# Why can't you do marriages durring chaturmas, and what scripture talk about it?

Tags: scripture

I have been thinking and tbh i don't think there would be anything religiously wrong in getting married during chaturmass, since back in the Vedic times situations were different and now it is different. but i really want to learn and understand as to why,

Answer (score 4):

During Chaturmas period the gods rest and Lord Vishnu sleeps too. Hindu marriages are done with Lord Vishnu being kept as the witness (Shaligrama sakshi). That is why auspicious ceremonies like marriages are not held during these 4 months.

Chaturmas period is a period for austerity, abstinence and control over senses where Japa, Tapa, Vrata, bathing in sacred Tirthas yield the best results.

Quoting from the [Chaturmasya Mahatmya chapter of the book "Essence of Skanda Purana"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana33.html):

> **Chaturmasya Mahatmya and Shodasopacharas (Sixteen Services)**
>
> Chaturmasa or Four Month period commencing from Ashadha Shukla Ekadasi
> known as Devashayani Ekadasi (when God sleeps) till Kartika Shukla
> Ekadasi called Deva Prabodhini Ekadasi(when God is awake) is observed
> by persons of all ‘Varnas’with piety, Indriya Nigraha or Self control
> of Organs and Rituals. (Chaturmasa commences from Ashadha Purnima or
> Guru Purnima till Kartika Purnima for Sanyasins).
>
> Bhagavan Vishnu is stated to rest on ‘Ksheera Sagar’ (Ocean of Milk)
> during the Chaturmasya (Four Month) period and hence all Oceans,
> Rivers, Ponds and Water Bodies acquire divinity. Bathing in these
> Places is thus a significant exercise as Bhagavan Narayana spreads out
> Himself in water and destroys sins of those who bathe especially in
> the holy rivers like Pushkar, Prayag, Narmada, Bhaskara Kshetra,
> Prachi Saraswati, Samudra Sangam, Godavari, or Ganga. For example,
> bathing in Narmada even for three days with great piety and
> concentration results in demolition of sins; Godavari baths for a
> fortnight of early mornings secure devastation of old and current
> account failings in life and pave the way to Vishnudham. ‘Snaans’with
> tila and Amla mix or Tulasi or Bilva leaves placed on head and
> reciting Vishnu namaas on the lips and in mind during as many days as
> possible during the Chaturmasya would yield instant results by
> providing physical fresshness, mental contentment and purity of
> thought and action. According to Scriptures, Snaan is the first step
> of physical clealiness and ‘Anthassuddhi’ (internal purity), before
> taking up any task to invoke the Almighty. During the four-month
> period of Sacrifice and Sanctity, ‘Tarpanas’ to Devas, Rishis and
> Pitras after the holy baths are natural duties, followed by
> ‘Anushthaana’, Agni havans, Veda Paatha, Satsang, Bhakti, and
> charities especially of Anna daanas. **The Chaturmasya is the period for
> abstinence, ‘Ishta Vasthu Parithyaga’ or leaving out material dear to
> oneself and strict following up of daily ‘niyamas’ and continuous
> recital of Bhagavan’s glories by way of hymns, Japas, Mantras and
> Bhakti Songs.**

Comment: Side question. Can one do graha pravesh in this period? Does it require Lord Vishnu to be a witness

Comment: I don't think any auspicious ceremonies can be held Griha Pravesh included @Carmensandiego